# If I have a void pointer, how do I put an int into it?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have an array of arbitrary values, so I have defined it as an array of void pointers, so I can point to any kind of information (like `int`, character arrays, etc). However, how do I actually assign an `int` to it?

Take for example these initializations:

```
void* data[10];
int x = 100;
```

My intuition would think this, but this gives a compile error:

```
data[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*(data[0]) = x;
```

Also I thought about using `&x`, but I would take the address of a local variable, which (to my understanding) would be cleared after exiting from the procedure. So if I have a local variable `x`, how would I get it into a void pointer type of variable correctly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
*((int*)data[0])=x;
```

will do it.

You might want to consider using a union.  Something like this:

```
union myvalues
{
    int i;
    double d;
    long l;
};
```

You could then have

```
union myvalues *foo[10];
foo[0] = malloc(sizeof(union myvalues));
foo[0]->i = x;
```

You can also `typedef` the union.  `sizeof(union myvalues)` will be the maximum of `sizeof` the members.  So if you have `int i;` and `char c[40]` in the union, `sizeof(union myvalues)` will be 40.  Writing to `i` will then overwrite the first 4 characters in `c` (assuming your ints are 4 bytes).

Comment: Indeed, good point.  I was going with the closest to the original.

Comment: Thanks but would this work with character array pointers as well (char *). And would this not cause alignment issues on some platforms? And finally, if I have a char[40] it seems kind of a waste of memory to reserve 40 bytes if I'm only going to use 4. :-)

Comment: As I understand matters, unions are aligned at a boundary suitable for their largest member, so no alignment problems.

char[40]: sure.  This was just a handy example for explaining size.

You could include a char* in the union. This might end up with two allocations (allocating the union, then the buffer pointed to by the char*).  There would be two ways to avoid that: 

a) as Neil suggests above, just have an array of unions instead of an array of pointers to unions

b) Do something like foo[0]=malloc(sizeof(union myvalues)+length_of_str+1); foo[0]->c=((char*)foo[0])+sizeof(union myvalues);

Comment: Why do you need to deference it? doesn't the [] operator do that? (like if you have int *n; you just do n[0] = 23; not *(n[0]) = 23;)

Comment: @Jonathan. the questioner had a void* data[10]; - i.e. an array of void*s.  data[0] is therefore a void* and needs dereferencing.  IOW, your example would be int **n, and you're doing n[0][0] = 23; or *(n[0])=23;

Answer (score 11):

```
*((int *)data[0]) = x;
```

A copy of x will be made, so the fact it is a local variable is not important.

Answer (score 4):

for aliasing reasons its far better to do

```
mempcy( data[0], &x, sizeof( int ) );
```

As it happens the compiler will optimise the memcpy call out as sizeof( int ) is a constant value but it won't break various aliasing rules.

Comment: I assume Goz is worried about type-punning, but since you can't dereference `void*`, it's always safe AFAIK to alias with a `void*` pointer. Just don't dereference it after casting to anything other than `int*` or `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use a cast to make the assignment, it is probably much cleaner to write the code like:

```
void *data[ 10 ];
int x = 100;
int *p;

p = malloc( sizeof *p );
data[ 0 ] = p;
*p = x;
```

Comment: I agree with you for this simple example, and that was the method I went for first. The problem however is that there are many different possible data types and such, so I would have to declare a lot of temporary local variables that might or might not be used at a certain execution.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*((int*)data[0]) = x;
```

or

```
(int) (*(data[0])) = x;
```

don't forget to

```
free (data[0]);
```

afterwards.